# Hacking radio buttons behavior with jQuery (uncheck group)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

For a project I need to use two radio buttons in a group, and need to uncheck the radio button that is checked, on click.

I have tried something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']:checked").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        alert('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

It doesn't even alert when I click the checked radio button.

Whenever I call this in my console:

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").prop('checked', false);
```

It does uncheck the checked radio button, so that part should work.

Comment: did you wrap this code in a block that runs AFTER DOM loads?

Comment: if your alert itsn't working than the selector must be wrong. Try `$("input[type='radio']:checked").change(function(e) {}`

Comment: @Banana yes, I load this JS in the footer, after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: he means to wrap it in either $(document).ready or $(function(){})

Comment: @godmode this couldn't work because I need it to trigger when clicking an already checked element. Doing that wouldn't trigger the change event.

Comment: Oh, yeah also that. All my JS is after the DOM

Answer (score 5):

Actually when you use `click` it cant happen that way use `mousedown` instead

Working snippet attached

```js
$(function(){
  $('#wrapper').on('mousedown', 'input[type=radio]',function(e){
 if(!$(e.target).is(':checked')){
  return true;
 }
 e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
    alert('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <input type=radio name=hello />
 <input type=radio name=hello />
 <input type=radio name=hello checked/>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Looks great! However, it is not working for me, could this be because I use bootstrap styling?

Comment: Initially I didn't wrap my code in `$.ready` check the last edit see it it works

Comment: can you check what all scripts are listening to the the `input[type=radio]`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. When the page loads you are only binding the `.click` function to SELECTED check boxes. Change `$("input[type='radio']:checked")` to `$("input[type='radio']")`